# 0-glusterfs: failed to get the 'volume file' from server

Tags: 14.04, cluster

How come I'm unable to mount glusterfs brick? Any idea?

Ubuntu 14.04, glusterfs 3.4.2

```
$ sudo mount -t glusterfs webdir  /var/www/
[2016-05-31 07:23:24.201840] C [glusterfsd.c:1406:parse_cmdline] 0-glusterfs: ERROR: parsing the volfile failed (No such file or directory)

USAGE: /usr/sbin/glusterfs [options] [mountpoint]
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.

$ sudo tail /var/log/glusterfs/var-www.log
[2016-05-31 07:11:57.047748] W [glusterfsd.c:1002:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_notify+0x105) [0x7fce5d449e15] (-->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_handle_reply+0x90) [0x7fce5d449c10] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(mgmt_getspec_cbk+0x449) [0x7fce5db00d09]))) 0-: received signum (0), shutting down
[2016-05-31 07:11:57.047768] I [fuse-bridge.c:5260:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/var/www'.
[2016-05-31 07:17:33.573486] I [glusterfsd.c:1910:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.4.2 (/usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-id=/bricks/web/ --volfile-server=node2 /var/www)
[2016-05-31 07:17:33.575886] I [socket.c:3480:socket_init] 0-glusterfs: SSL support is NOT enabled
[2016-05-31 07:17:33.575927] I [socket.c:3495:socket_init] 0-glusterfs: using system polling thread
[2016-05-31 07:17:33.577237] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1574:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-glusterfs: failed to get the 'volume file' from server
[2016-05-31 07:17:33.577267] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1674:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-mgmt: failed to fetch volume file (key:/bricks/web/)
[2016-05-31 07:17:33.577441] W [glusterfsd.c:1002:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_notify+0x105) [0x7f0bd2996e15] (-->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_handle_reply+0x90) [0x7f0bd2996c10] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(mgmt_getspec_cbk+0x449) [0x7f0bd304dd09]))) 0-: received signum (0), shutting down
[2016-05-31 07:17:33.577462] I [fuse-bridge.c:5260:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/var/www'.
[2016-05-31 07:17:33.596794] W [glusterfsd.c:1002:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f0bd228c47d] (-->/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182) [0x7f0bd255f182] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(glusterfs_sigwaiter+0xd5) [0x7f0bd3048ef5]))) 0-: received signum (15), shutting down
```

Below are volume info

```
$ sudo gluster volume info

Volume Name: webdir
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: d41dca8e-caff-47f4-a1db-fefe7364235c
Status: Started
Number of Bricks: 1 x 3 = 3
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: node2:/bricks/web
Brick2: node3:/bricks/web
Brick3: node4:/bricks/web
```

Comment: stopping glusterfs-server on all nodes and ran `glusterd --xlator-option *.upgrade=on N` did not solve this

Comment: it seems that I need to use *node2:webdir* instead of just *webdir*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using below command

`sudo mount -t glusterfs node2:webdir  /var/www/`

I missed the node hostname before volume name.